# Where / and filtering in a query returns empty values on matching results

Tags: loopbackjs

After working with loopback for the past 6 months, i have now encountered a problem i can't seem to figure out the reason for.

My problem occurs when using loopbacks, "where" with a "and" condition.

```
    Like.find({
    "where: {
      "and": [{
          "relation_id": ctx.instance.relation_id
        },
        {
          "user_id": ctx.options.accessToken.userId
        }
        ]
      }
  })
```

Above is the call with the where/and filter included.
I console.log the values before the call and see:

"ctx.instance.relation_id" which prints "59a32764029ab660b1c7f862"
"ctx.options.accessToken.userId" which prints "59a32597c606a85b5e08db18"

And below is the object i am trying to query:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("59a5cade884d8c48e135768c"),
  "user_id" : "59a32597c606a85b5e08db18",
  "relation_id" : "59a32764029ab660b1c7f862",
  "created_at" : ISODate("2017-08-29T22:13:18.209+02:00"),
  "status" : NumberInt("1")
}
```

Now. Calling the find() function without the "and" condition for just one of the values, either user_id or relation_id, returns the expected result, but with the "and" it returns an empty array.

The official Loopback documentation gives this examples for using the where/and filter:

```
Post.find({where: {and: [{title: 'My Post'}, {content: 'Hello'}]}}, 
      function (err, posts) {
        ...
});
```

[as shown here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Where-filter.html#and--or)

And as far as i can tell, my query matches it completely, but still don't get the expected results. I know that there could be many reasons why it fails, but i was hoping someone here, maybe could give some pointers or provide insight i could use to solve my issue.

Thanks

Comment: How did you insert that object into the database? It's possible that loopback is trying to search on `user_id` and `relation_id` as an `ObjectId`, but they are stored as strings in the database.

Comment: if that was the case, then the example object would display it as well like it does with it's _id:
ObjectId("59a5cade884d8c48e135768c")
The object is copy/pasted as the raw JSON data from the mongodb